# How to determine width of \textls? \settowidth doesn't work

Tags: microtype, width, letterspacing

Using `microtype`'s `\textls`, how can I determine the width of the resulting text? Here is a MWE that does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[log-functions=false]{expl3}
\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse}

\usepackage[stretch=10]{microtype}

\ExplSyntaxOn


\newcommand{\cftpartfont}[1]{\normalfont\textls*[80]{\uppercase{#1}}}

\newlength{\lswidth}

\settowidth{\lswidth}{\cftpartfont{VIII\space}}
\typeout{\the\lswidth}

\settowidth{\lswidth}{VIII\space}
\typeout{\the\lswidth}

\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \cftpartfont{VIII\space} }
\typeout{\the\box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box}

\show\show

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

```
22.22pt
22.22pt
22.22pt
> \show=\show.
```

What to do?

Comment: Are you sure you want to letterspace Roman numbers? I'm not.

Comment: @egreg: very good point! I will change that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
25.28894pt
22.22226pt
25.28894pt
```

Just move `\begin{document}` :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[log-functions=false]{expl3}
\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse}

\usepackage[stretch=10]{microtype}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn


\newcommand{\cftpartfont}[1]{\normalfont\textls*[80]{\uppercase{#1}}}

\newlength{\lswidth}

\settowidth{\lswidth}{\cftpartfont{VIII\space}}
\typeout{\the\lswidth}

\settowidth{\lswidth}{VIII\space}
\typeout{\the\lswidth}

\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \cftpartfont{VIII\space} }
\typeout{\the\box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box}

\show\show


\end{document}
```

Comment: darn... how then can I define in a package a TOC layout that says "PART I  TITLE" and that indents the chapters by the amount of "PART I", which is `\textls`ed?

Comment: @MiB I would gueess you need to stick your measuring code in \AtBeginDocument, or measure at the time, at the start of the toc. It is best to delay anyway as the fonts might change in the preamble if someone loads font settings after you have measured